# Is this a proof of the Hardy-Littlewood inequality?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, conjectures

V.V. Miasoyedov posted [a paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.07939) to the arXiv claiming a proof of the Hardy-Littlewood conjecture $\pi(x+y) \le \pi(x)+\pi(y)$. It seems a bit off, and not only because the conjecture is widely believed false (incompatible with the $k$-tuple conjecture, as pointed out by Richards.) But when I looked it over I couldn't get a good feeling of what was going on at a higher level, and the details that I saw looked right. (My copy of v1 has each sentence up to (2.3) marked with a check.)

Can anyone confirm that the paper is in error?

Comment: After a quick glance, seems hackish too me.

Comment: I think checking claimed proofs is off-topic on this site.

Comment: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/942/4832

Comment: Great question. There seems to be many elementary case by case considerations in the proof. Perhaps it's possible to divide the proof into parts of not more than, say, 10 lines. Then members of MO who are interested in the proof could check each a single part. The collaboration of the participants could be coordinated here.

Comment: @tj_: That's not the purpose of this site. It was neither designed for discussions nor for collaboration. Those are not the expectation for many who come here. It would set a bad precedent. We could write a book in post-its stuck to a tree but there are better places for that. Make a wiki and invite people if you are so interested.

Comment: The `proof' doesn't seem to use anything specific about primes. Seems to use only that $\pi$ is the counting function of a strongly monotonous sequence $p_1,p_2,\dots$ of integers. Unless I'm overlooking something (have spent less than 30 seconds on the paper), it is utter nonsense.